# Best practice reusing components with MVVM

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I was wondering if someone found some clever solution to reuse components (multiple views) when working with MVVM.

By *component* I mean a set of views that end up being reused in an app.
For instance, an empty state formed of an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, and let's also add some sort of `ClickListener` for the text, for the sake of the example.

Now, what I want to do is to reuse this view in multiple .xml files BUT providing different values for the text, the image, and bind the listener to action in the Fragment's `ViewModel`.

What I've been doing is create a `CustomEmptyState` that would extend a `LinearLayout` or some kind of Layout and add `Custom Attributes` to it.

So, in the end, I would use my custom view like this:

```
<com.whatever.customViews.CutomEmptyState
     app:image="@drawable/someImage"
     app:text="@string/empty_text"
     app:onTextClicked="@{viewModel.onEmptyStateClicked()}" />
```

My question would be, is there a different approach to this? A better one? What I dislike about this is writing the custom attributes with `<declare-styleable>` and all because then I have to keep track of 3 files:

1. The `.xml` layout of the base view
2. The `.java/.kt` of the view with the boilerplate code to handle the attributes
3. The `<declare-styleable>` with all the attributes

Is there any way to combine 2 and 3?

Comment: try like this
<com.whatever.customViews.CutomEmptyState
     app:image="@drawable/someImage"
     app:text="@string/empty_text"
     app:onTextClicked="@{viewModel::onEmptyStateClicked}" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you have to display some text value which you are sure will be databinded.

Then, if you databind the value, then there is a way, but not an elegant way.

declare a variable in the custom view like:  `private var status = ""`

then write a setter function:

```
fun setStatus(status: String) {
    this.status = status
    //refresh your views based on value or set this to the text view 
}
```

and then databind like this:

```
app:status="@{viewModel.status}"
```

so that you don't need to declare the stylable anymore

Comment: I was not aware that it would work with setters. I'm wondering why you don't consider this an elegant solution. I find it very nice. I mean basically you replace the attributes for the setters, right? Maybe it could become overwhelming for a view with a lot of setters.

Comment: Hi @GhimpuLucianEduard,  If the solution address your issue, can you please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  <com.whatever.customViews.CutomEmptyState
       app:image="@drawable/someImage"
       app:text="@string/empty_text"
       app:onTextClicked="@{viewModel::onEmptyStateClicked}" />




public void onEmptyStateClicked(View view){
     your code
     }
```